# How can i check if file exists based on a partial file name?

Tags: php, file

Im trying to check if a file exists in my folder but i only have a partial filename to check it against, Is there a way to check it?

**For example i have the following:**

```
God_of_War
```

The filename is actually called:

```
God_of_War_PSP(USA).rar
```

Is there some kind of LIKE for file_exists function ? or can i use str_pos somehow ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You could use something similar to the following:

```
$fileSearch = "God_of_War";
$files = glob("/path/*" . $fileSearch . "*");
if(count($files) > 0) echo "File Exists!";
```

Comment: If i have 2 files, say for example `God_Of_War(USA)` and `God_Of_War_2(USA)` Will that say file exists if there is a file called `God_Of_War_PSP(USA).rar` ?

Comment: Yes. The asterisk matches any character and any number of characters. Without it though you would have to search for the exact name. So any file containing the string `God_Of_War` will be found.

Comment: But if i only have the file `God_Of_War` on my PC, I still want it to download `God_Of_War_2` is that possible?

Comment: If you're searching for that string, then it will return `God_Of_War_2` since the string is in there. `'God_Of_War'_2`. Do a var_dump on `$files` and you'll see what is returned.

Comment: No, it should only return the files that have that exact string inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something like:

```
$search_string = 'God_of_War';
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/folder/');
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
$res = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^'.$search_string.'/', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
var_dump($res);
```